# Cleanest way to structure unit tests in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I usually structure my projects in this way:

```
root
  src
    __init__,py
    main.py
    utils.py
    xyz.py
  tests
    __init__.py
    test_main.py
    test_utils.py
    test_xyz.py
  README.md
  LICENSE
  Other stuff...
```

In the tests I import the functions I need to test with imports like `from src.main import my_function`

And then run tests from the root using `python -m unittest discover`

That works... kinda. If `main.py` imports other modules in the `src` package (e.g. `import utils`) the test crashes with an ImportError. The reason is that unittest add to PATH the directory where is launched, therefore it recognizes `src.main` but not the relative imports inside it.

The solution I found is to insert in `test/__init__.py` a statement like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./src")
```

This adds the entire src folder to the PYTHONPATH. It works but I feel this is quite ugly. What other solutions are available? Checking similar question I didn't found a solution that allows to both run tests and execute the main package without having to change code each time...

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't treat `src` as a package; it's just a *directory* that contains all your source code. Perhaps `src/main.py`, `src/pkg/{utils,xyz}.py`, then `main.py` can import `pkg.{utils,xzy}` regardless of their relative locations (as long as `pkg` is found in the Python search path *not* `PATH`).

Comment: Don't worry too much about the test setup being ugly. They are the *only* files that are (realistically) going to be importing `main` (which I assume is intended to be executed as a script), so it's not a big deal if `src` needs to be temporarily added to `PYTHONPATH` just for the test runner.

Comment: I usually prefer to keep tests close by to the code they test. In this case it is easier to refactor and move the code around. In your case, I would put `tests` directory under `src`, it would probably solve the import problem you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always point people to the packaging suggestion in the *[Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)*. Creating a `pyproject.toml` file supports you doing a `pip install` of your package. During development you can do the install in *[Development Mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html)*.
This will allow your tests to import the functions in a familiar python style of:

```
from <your_package>.main import my_function
from <your_package>.utils import my_util_func
```

If you do this there is no need to fiddle with the path settings